# Selenium switching windows failure

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-iedriver

I am writing a web scraper using Selenium which needs to be multi-threaded

```
// selenium imports from org.openqa omitted
public class wpn
{
    private String sessionId = "";
    private String windowHandle = "";
    private WebDriver driver;

    public wpn (String id)
    {
        sessionId = id;
    }

    public void openDriver (String driverType)
    {
        if (driverType.equals ("ie"))
        {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
            capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
            capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "c:\\temp\\ieDriver.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
        else if (driverType.equals ("chrome"))
        {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\temp\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver (capabilities);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
        else if (driverType.equals ("phantom"))
        {
            File file = new File("c:\\temp\\phantomJSDdriver.exe");
            System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath ());
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {"--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"});
            driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
            Dimension dimension = new Dimension (1280, 1024);
            driver.manage().window().setSize (dimension);
        }
        else if (driverType.equals ("firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty ("webdriver.gecko.driver", "c:\\temp\\geckodriver.exe");
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions ();
            options.setBinary (c:\\temp\\firefoxdriver.exe");
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
        else
        {
            System.println("unrecognised driver type " + driverType); 
        }

        System.setProperty ("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
    }

    public void login (String loginUrl)
    {
        driver.get(loginUrl);
        windowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle ();
    }

    public void getInfo (String infoUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            String wh = driver.getWindowHandle ();
            if (!wh.matches(windowHandle))
            {
                driver.switchTo(windowHandle);
            }

            driver.get(infoUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println (e.getMessage ());
        }
    }
}

int main (String[] args)
{
    wpn session_1 = new wpn ("101");
    wpn session_2 = new wpn ("202");

    String driverType = args[0];
    session_1.openDriver (driverType);
    session_2.openDriver (driverType);

    session_1.login ("http://myService.com/login");
    session_2.login ("http://myService.com/login");

    session_2.info ("http://myService.com/info");
    // proceeds OK, because window handles match

    session_1.info ("http://myService.com/info");
    // produces failure when attempting to switch to session_1's window
}
```

With the ie driver, the error is something like:

```
No window found  
Build info: version: '3.5.0', revision: '8def36e068', time: '2017-08-10T23:00:22.093Z'  
System info: host: 'HUWG', ip: '192.168.0.215', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'  
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver  
Capabilities [{acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=11, se:ieOptions={nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0.0, ie.ensureCleanSession=true, elementScrollBehavior=0.0, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, requireWindowFocus=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:40976/, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000.0, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=dismiss, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows, setWindowRect=true, platform=ANY}]  
Session ID: cd72bba0-f105-43a8-a234-cbb494c19d8c
```

With Chrome it is something like:

```
no such window  
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)  
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498  
 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)  
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds  
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z'  
System info: host: 'HUWG', ip: '192.168.0.215', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'  
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver  
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6..., userDataDir: C:\Users\gallonh\AppData\Lo...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 67.0.3396.99, webStorageEnabled: true}  
Session ID: c4c74d5258c723a0a09dbbf7284b1c48
```

With phantomJS driver, it is something like:

```
no such window  
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)  
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498  
 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)  
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds  
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z'  
System info: host: 'HUWG', ip: '192.168.0.215', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'  
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver  
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6..., userDataDir: C:\Users\gallonh\AppData\Lo...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 67.0.3396.99, webStorageEnabled: true}  
Session ID: c4c74d5258c723a0a09dbbf7284b1c48
```

With the Firefox driver, the handle for every  window opened by Selenium is "4294967297" so the window is never switched.

For the IE and phantomJS drivers I am building the application with selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar. For the chrome and firefox drivers I am building the application with selenium-server-standalon-3.13.0.jar.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You're using matches which is a regex matcher. `driver.getWindowHandle` returns a String, and you should use `equals` to check for equality. Also, since you aren't switching windows after `session.login(...)` and before `session.info(...)`, it is redundant to check if the driver is pointing to the same window.

You have initialised two separate instances of drivers which refer to their own browser windows. There is no 'crosstalk' between the driver instances which drive their own browser session.

If you still want to check if you're still pointing to the same window, use `wh.equals(windowHandle)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided the error stack trace using the following *WebDrivervariants*:

- **InternetExplorerDriver`**
- **chromedriver=2.40**
- **PhantomJSDriver**

First of all it is worth to mention that different *Browser Clients* renders the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) in a different way. Possibly if you could have narrowed down your question to a specific *WebDriver*/*Browser Client* variant, debugging the issue could have been much more easier.

Analysing all the three chunks of error trace logs it seems the issue is with **switching windows/tabs** where the error reads as:

- **`No window found`** (*InternetExplorerDriver*)
- **`no such window`** (*chromedriver=2.40*)
- **`no such window`** (*PhantomJSDriver*)

However, your main issue seems to be the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Though you are using ***selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar*** and ***selenium-server-standalon-3.13.0.jar*** alternatively
- Your ***JDK*** version seems to be **1.8.0_144** which is pretty ***old*** and ***ancient***.

### Solution

Configure your *Test Bed* to execute your *Test Suite* with the most recent GA binaries:

- [***Java SE Development Kit 8u181***](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- [***selenium-server-standalon-3.x.y.jar***](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)